# SELECT: getting event on onChange

Tags: antd

I built a table with a column with a "  linked multiselect" filter, where the options of the second select depend on the first selection, and so on.

The problem is that as soon as I select an item, the filter dropdown close. I would like to close the popup when I finished all the selection.

I thought to intercept the onchange event in order to stop the propagation of the event. But it seems it's not possible.

Another option is to intercept the onClick event on the `<option>`, I tried but it didn't work.

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/8498m8ykxj

Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup container of the select (the options) is outside the filter dropdown.

Moving it inside (Select.getPopupContainer) solved the problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/8498m8ykxj

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to be that guy that does not understand what you are doing and gives advice. But if you need a multiple select, I would suggest to use a "[multiple selection](https://codesandbox.io/s/o5kx47y426)" input as you can find in the [antd doc](https://ant.design/components/select/). 
An other solution would be to use a [Menu](https://ant.design/components/menu/) with chehkbox for each item. I think it would be much more easy to use.

That is just an idea.

Have a good day anyway

Comment: I wasn't be very clear in the name of the control I need. Let's call it "linked multiple select". The value of the second select depends on the selection of the first one, and so on.

Comment: Ok, well I understand why you did that trhen :) Sry about the "not so usefull" (useless) comment.